# Arithmetic types in Arduino

Tags: data-type

I'm looking for a complete list of the arithmetic types in the Arduino framework.
On the Internet I found various incomplete lists: sometimes there is `short`, sometimes `word`, but other types are missing.

Could someone please provide an exhaustive list of the arithmetic data types in Arduino, including the C/C++ types and the Arduino-defined types (or aliases, e.g. the one created among others in Arduino.h with `typedef uint8_t byte;`) with a short description? If two types are identical please include both names in the list but making clear that they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have integers in 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits, both signed and unsigned. You have float and double, which can be the same thing on some systems.

There are many names given to those variable types, some standard or ubiquitous, some vague or unique, or change depending on which type of CPU you are working with.

The names aren't important, since they only exist in the source code. All that matters is the underlying size. Names of the same underlying size and signedness are interchangeable at will.

For example:

- uint8_t = unsigned char
- int32_t = long = int on 32 but systems
- uint16_t = unsigned short = int on 8 bit systems

As you can see `int` changes depending on the system you are on. So it is best to stick to specifically named types. I always use the `[u]int[N]_t` types.

So you have:

- uint8_t
- int8_t
- uint16_t
- int16_t
- uint32_t
- int32_t
- uint64_t
- int64_t

And:

- float
- double (if the compiler supports double on the platform you are compiling for, otherwise it is just float).

Arduino itself provides some more unique variable names that are completely nonstandard, such as `byte` for `unsigned char`.

In `short` (pun intended), stick to variables that specifically define their type if you are worried about how big they all are, and avoid all the rest.

For overloading the compiler will automatically "upscale" the variables to the best fitting available function (known as *type promotion*) unless functions are flagged as `explicit`, so you can have a function with a `long` parameter and pass any integer variable up to and including a `long` in size. The same with `float` / `double` types - if your function takes a `double` you can pass it a `float`. Useful when you don't know if the target provides a real `double` or not - just use `double` and it will work regardless with either `double` or `float`.

Comment: And all the `_Fract` and `_Accum` types in avr-gcc 4.8+.

Comment: GCC has introduced all sorts of weird and wonderful types for special jobs. I have never seen any of them actually be used. People tend to use assembly or DSP instructions for optimisation instead of strange types.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino "language" is actually C/C++. GNU GCC and tool chain are used. The Arduino IDE uses a preprocessor to make it easier for beginners by removing some of the C/C++ requirements such as forward declaration of functions.

The GNU AVR GCC data types and representation, and the answer to your question can be found on the project Wiki page; https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc

For C/C++ there are build-in data types but also a set of standards. One of the standard header files with data types is `stdint.h`. http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html

`Arduino.h` and additional header files within the Arduino core libary contains the extensions or redefinitions made. The complete reference list; https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage

Cheers!